# How to align my extra button left to the close button in leaflet popup window

Tags: html, css, leaflet

I`ve managed to add a custom button under the close button in the leaflet popup window. Now i want this button to be left next to the close button. How can i do this?

[image: What i have now]

css:

```
.leaflet-container a.leaflet-popup-edit-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding: 4px 4px 0 0;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18px;
  height: 14px;
  font: 16px/14px Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #c3c3c3;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: transparent;
  }
  .leaflet-container a.leaflet-popup-edit-button:hover {
  color: #999;
  }
```

html:

```
<a class="leaflet-popup-edit-button" href="/editbs.php?id='+current.id+'" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt fa-xs"></i></a>
```

Thanks and greetings from Germany!

Comment: I suppose you could just use top: 0 or some other negative top value.

Comment: If I use top: 0 the pencil is inside the x

Comment: Then try changing right: 0 to something like right: 20px;

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of what you're trying to achieve.  The HTML you sent requires FontAwesome, so I replaced it with normal text.

#### What you need to do

- Set your parent container to `position: relative;`
- Set both the *close* and *edit* buttons to `position: absolute;`
- Then position both of them to the top right.

It will help with alignment if you can set the width of the *close* button.  That way you can add padding, spacing, and width of the *close* button together, this will be the value of your `right:;` declaration on the *edit* button.

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border:1px solid;
  padding: 6px;
}

.close {
  position:absolute;
  width: 12px;
  top: 6px;
  right: 6px;
}

.pencil {
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(6px + 12px + 6px);
  top: 6px;
}

h1 {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <span class="close">x</span>
  <span class="pencil">Pencil</span>
  <h1>Content</h1>
</section>
```